# DRF viewset overriding get_template_names throws ValueError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In [this ticket](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1000) from 2013 it is stated:

> The .action attribute will be set when inside a ViewSet, to whichever action is being triggered (eg. list). You can use this if you're inside a method eg get_template_names and need to get access to whichever action is being handled.

However, when I try to conduct a simple experiment thus:

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for the example model.
    """
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerialiser

    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.action == 'list':
            return ['example/list_examples.html']
```

With settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'
    ),
}
```

I get:

```
Internal Server Error: /example/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 109, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 174, in render
    return template_render(template, context, request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/compat.py", line 279, in template_render
    return template.render(context, request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 267, in make_context
    context.push(original_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 59, in push
    return ContextDict(self, *dicts, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 18, in __init__
    super(ContextDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required
```

From browsing the source, it would seem that get_template_names is expected to return an iterable.

What am I doing wrong?

### An update:

Upgrading Django to latest changes the exception to something more obvious, a TypeError:

```
Internal Server Error: /example/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 72, in rendered_content
    ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 176, in render
    return template_render(template, context, request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/compat.py", line 340, in template_render
    return template.render(context, request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 64, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py", line 287, in make_context
    raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than ReturnList.
[09/Jul/2017 13:22:26] "GET /example/ HTTP/1.1" 500 91963
```

The context appears to be an array of OrderedDicts:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/compat.py in template_render
        return template.render(context, request=request) ...
▼ Local vars
context [OrderedDict([(u'url', u'http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/1/'), ('created', u'2017-06-26T19:48:08.980344Z'), ('updated', u'2017-07-08T21:54:28.505181Z'), ('name', u'Example 1')]), OrderedDict([(u'url', u'http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/2/'), ('created', u'2017-06-26T21:45:36.310536Z'), ('updated', u'2017-06-26T21:45:36.310636Z'), ('name', u'Example 2')]), OrderedDict([(u'url', u'http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/3/'), ('created', u'2017-06-26T21:46:00.390582Z'), ('updated', u'2017-06-26T21:46:00.390620Z'), ('name', u'Example 3')]), OrderedDict([(u'url', u'http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/4/'), ('created', u'2017-06-26T21:46:07.777296Z'), ('updated', u'2017-06-26T21:46:07.777335Z'), ('name', u'Example 4')])]
request <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x7f027aa31cd0>
templat <django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x7f027aa31190>
```

Seems something is happening to the context.

### Second Update

So, my initial belief that this was related to get_template_names was just wrong. Apparently it has nothing to do with it. This seemingly about using ViewSets with TemplateHTMLRenderer. Is this working as intended?

From the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/):

> The TemplateHTMLRenderer class expects the response to contain a dictionary of context data, and renders an HTML page based on a template that must be specified either in the view or on the response.
>
> The StaticHTMLRender class expects the response to contain a string of
>   the pre-rendered HTML content.
>
> Because static HTML pages typically have different behavior from API
>   responses you'll probably need to write any HTML views explicitly,
>   rather than relying on the built-in generic views.

For the record I am aware of and have been using the format of overriding methods as in:

```
def list(self, request, **kwargs):
    if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':
        examples = {'examples': self.get_queryset()}
        return Response(examples, template_name='example/list_examples.html')

    return super(ExampleViewSet, self).list(self, request, **kwargs)
```

However, I had thought that this was mainly for being explicit about which template you wanted to render on the view. To avoid overriding all such methods, I was hoping to use the get_template_names approach.